# How to Prevent from re-uploading a file?

Tags: file

i have an Educational website and i create always pdf files from my learning and ad them for download 
but there is many learchers that download my files and reupload them somewhere else 
i used google dmca but is there any way to Prevent from re-uploading my files?

Comment: No. If they have the file, they can upload it somewhere else.

Comment: Why do you afraid of reuploading your files ? Put links to original site into the PDF and get profit of this. More copies, more downloads, more popularity to your resource.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use your `.htaccess` to prevent [hotlinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotlinking), but even if you do that, you'll again have the problem that when someone views the document via an in-browser extension (e.g. Adobe Reader, Foxit PDF Reader), they can save it and **you've lost control** over what they can do with it. Or, depending on how you've set up your site, they can simply directly download it, leaving you again back at square one.

Hence, **the solution is to bypass direct access to the document.** And, there are a number of ways to do that, which varies based on technique and web software (platform) used.

However, since you didn't mention a particular platform or technology: **you can use web controllers ([MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) type controllers) to broker the dynamic viewing and displaying of the documents in tandem with a client-side tool / plugin to do the displaying for you (much like [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/)).**

However, Scribd uses a proprietary Flash PDF viewer called **iPaper**, and while it isn't available for use, you can find many other alternatives on the web. One that comes highly recommended (there's even a tag on SO for it) is [FlexPaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/), an open source plugin that implements a client-side web-based PDF viewer - which I think will suit your needs perfectly ([from here](https://code.google.com/p/flexpaper/)):

> This project provides a light weight document viewer component
>   enabling PDF files to be viewed without having any PDF reader software
>   installed. This project provides both Flex library and stand-alone web
>   version.

Here are some demos of it in action:

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/demo/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, by mistake posted partial comment. Anyway...
Why do you afraid of reuploading of your files ? Put links to original site into the PDF and get profit of this. More copies, more downloads, more popularity for your resource. If you indeed would like to make PDFs available from your site only, you have to hide files from users and provide some functionality to read them from your web site only (you can use existing sites of this type). That makes duplicating of your resources to be harder task, but be ready that many users reject to read it this way.